# Form is not Working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Marketplace in my website so seller can able to process their order in their dashboard.

In seller Dashboard **My order history** it shows all **order** with **order id** on that page I try to make process their order like **Invoice & Shipment**

But my problem is all order id shows with in foreach {} i also try to place code in that my code also have foreach.I placed code in this way foreach {foreach {}}

i think this is the reason it not working can you please anyone tell me the what is problem here?

```
   <div class="Check_now">


                                        <?php 
                                           $tracking = $this->getTrackingNumber($order->getId()); 
                                              if($tracking!=""){
                                                $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
                                              $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
                                               }
                                          ?>


        <!-- Custom Order Status display -->
                                <?php $custom_order_status = $order->getStatusLabel(); ?>
                                <?php //echo $custom_order_status;?>
        <!-- Custom Order Status display -->

        <?php if ($custom_order_status != 'Completed' && $custom_order_status !='Canceled'){?>
        <div class="wk_mp_order-info-box" style="display:none">
            <div class="box box-payment">

                <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'RTO'){?>

                    <div class="rto_status">
                        <strong><?php echo "This Order Has been  RTO State You can't able to Process"; ?>
                        </strong>
                    </div>

                <?php }
                    else{ ?>
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h2>
                        <span><?php echo $this->__('Process Your Order ') ?></span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
                <div class="box-content">
                <?php
                    $orderItems=$this->getOrderItems();
                    foreach($orderItems as $item) {
                        $item_status="";
                        foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $itemdata) {
                            if($itemdata->getProductId()==$item->getMageproid())
                                $item_status=$itemdata->getStatus();
                        }
                    }
                    $shipping_coll = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()));
                    if(count($shipping_coll)){?>
                        <?php 
                        $tracking=$this->getTrackingNumber($_order->getId());
                        if($tracking!=""){
                            $disabled=$tracking->getTrackingNumber()==''? "":"readonly='readonly'";
                            $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
                            $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
                            $shippingamount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                        }
                        if($_order->getStatus()=='pending' && $vendor_item_status!='canceled'){?>
                            <div class="scontent_status">
                                <span><?php echo $helper->__('Please Wait for Order Approve Your Admin');?></span></div>
                        <?php
                        }elseif(strtolower($vendor_item_status)=='canceled'){?>
                            <h3 class="scontent_status"><?php echo $helper->__('Order Canceled');?></h3>
                        <?php
                        }else{
                        ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber')?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">



                                <div class="shipping_top" style="display:none">
                                    <span class="shipping_service"><?php echo $helper->__('Carrier');?></span>
                                    <span class="row_total"><?php echo $helper->__('Tracking Number');?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items">
                                    <input class="required-entry" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" name="order_id"/>
                                    <div class="wk_item">
                                        <span class="carrier" style="display:none"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>
                                        <span class="row_total wk_track_input" style="display:none">
                                            <!-- <input value="<?php //echo $tracking->getTrackingNumber(); ?>" <?php //echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="tracking_id"/> -->
                                            <input value="0" type="text" name="tracking_id"/>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="order-status">
                                        <?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
                                            <?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                                    <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                                        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif;  ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>

                                            <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Generate Invoice') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
                                                <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Invoice') ?></span></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php } ?>


                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->
                                        <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'Invoiced'){?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        </a> 
                                        <?php }?>


                                        <?php if ($custom_order_status == 'Shipement'){?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/rtoorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
                                          <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
                                          <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('RTO') ?></span></span>
                                          </button>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php }?>

                                        <!-- Custom Order Status -->





                                    </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>


                        <?php 
                        } ?>
                    <?php
                    }else{
                        echo $_order->getShipping_description();
                    }?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
```

in check now part not working in that page

Comment: you are missing this `<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>` because there is not tracking variable in code. add this or remove this will work

Comment: I noticed that in your code neither your first `foreach($this->getCollection() as $res) {` nor `if($res['mageorderid']>0) {` does not have a closing bracket (`}`). It looks like you need to add `<?php } } ?>` at the very end of your file. Sure, if you pasted the entire part of your code here and did not miss anything.

Comment: @QaisarSatti where i need to add this

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza i didn't get this

Comment: `<span class="carrier" style="display:none"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>` remove this   and check it is working

Comment: Now no error but that form content not display

Comment: <div class="order-status"></div>

Comment: Ya now it's working but i can't able to process the order

Comment: then you have to add carrier in this because the form you  are posting need carrier too, can you add the $tracking code?

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code in you phtml and this method to `getTrackingNumber` to your block that will make it work.

```
<?php 
   $tracking = $this->getTrackingNumber($_order->getId()); 
      if($tracking!=""){
        $shipmentId = $tracking->getShipmentId();
      $invoiceId=$tracking->getInvoiceId();
       }
  ?>
```

Comment: Check my updated question i added that code and your code it's not working what is the problem on that

Comment: did you add method in block i ask you?

Comment: Check now question i add that form code as well as your code

Comment: can you give me live link so i can check?

Comment: you mean user name psw and url right?

Comment: yes if you have demo website

Comment: You got that page??

Comment: @Kothari Do not mention site urls with credeintials in public domain.

Comment: @Muk i will credeintials also that's demo site only

Comment: @Kothari no i don't get it?

Comment: you logged in that account

Comment: @Kothari sorry i don't get the credential

Comment: @Kothari remove that credential  this is where showing processing?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35120/discussion-between-kothari-and-qaisar-satti).